# RSpec/Capybara without Rails Setup for Page Objects/Support Files?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara, ui-automation, pageobjects

So im going to be writing a framework that uses Rspec/Capybara and Selenium to do some automation testing on an app. Im using purely RSpec (no rails) and im having some difficulties in getting everything setup correctly.

The problem I am running into is when im trying to include page object files into my specs. Right now my directory looks like:

spec (Actual .spec files go here, `spec_helper` is also here)
spec/support (Page Object Files go here)

In my page object files my first problem is it can't find the Capybara DSL unless I do: `include Capybara::DSL` at the top of each page object file (Which apparently isn't a good idea according to the warning message it gives me)

The other problem is that including my page object files in my tests Im needing to do a `require_relative` to the specific file (Which is sort of a pain) otherwise it can't find the class.

Is there something in `spec_helper` that will fix this? Im not an expert in ruby so I assume Im missing something. The Capybara DSL problem I can't figure out either for example requiring `require 'capybara/rspec'` doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options for Capybara::DSL -

1. Include Capybara::DSL into whatever base class you're using for your PageObjects so the Capybara methods are available in that class (as opposed to on the global object) - ie. the `include Capybara::DSL` goes inside the class definition - not at the top of the file.
2. Keep an instance of Capybara::Session in your page object instances and call all capybara methods on that session instance - `@my_session.find(...)`, etc.
3. Always use `Capybara.current_session` when calling Capybara methods - `Capybara.current_session.find(...)`, etc

As for the `require` issue -- you can either use `require_relative` to specify files to require based from the current file, or you use `require` and specify the location from the projects root (current working directory).  If you have a directory of files you want loaded you can add something like the following to your spec_helper.rb to tell it to load all the files

```
Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f }
```

Comment: Can you go into some detail on #2 and #3? I've seen when using capybara before people doing `session.click_button('something')` or `page.click_button('something')` what exactly is the difference when doing those as opposed to just saying `click_button('something')`. Seems like doing #1 would be the easiest?

Comment: @msmith1114 It all depends exactly what you're going for.  If you want to have multiple sessions all available independently then you probably want to be managing your own sessions and you'll be more like #2.  #3 would be if you don't want to include Capybara::DSL into a class for some reason (page is just an alias for `Capybara.current_session`).  There is no difference between `click_button('something')` and `Capybara.current_session.click_button('something')` if you've include Capybara::DSL into your class because the DSL just proxies everything to `Capybara.current_session`

Comment: I don't think I have any desire to do multiple sessions (Can't imagine why I would). So I guess i'll just stick with number one. 
Sidenote what does `page.click_button` represent compared to just `click_button`

Comment: They're identical - assuming `page` is the Capybara defined `page` method from Capybara::DSL -  `click_button` => `page.click_button` => `Capybara.current_session.click_button`

Comment: Ah gotcha. I guess I would only be doing multiple sessions if I was trying to do some multithreaded testing or something similar?

Comment: Yes -- multiple simultaneous sessions would generally be a web scraper or something similar.

Comment: For whatever reason `Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f }` in spec_helper doesn't seem to work surprisingly. I am able to just do `require` for each file. (Which I assume that's all that does above is just require every file`. Unless im just putting it in the wrong place in `spec_helper`.

Comment: Nevermind, looks like the problem was that im needing to require the main pageobject in my other class files :facepalm: (Which is kinda ugly unfortunately)